# Siebel application controls Spying(identifying) Using iBM Rational functional tester

Tags: testing, automation, siebel, rft

I am facing the problems while spying (Identifying) Siebel 7.8 version application components with RFT .  Currently using Internet explorer 11, and IBM Rational Functional Tester 8.6.0.3(floating license) and configured all settings to work on Siebel. But still facing spying issue. Some Siebel components are not spying. And it stopping automation testing
Any solution for this issue.

Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy

Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy

Configured Siebel settings & downloaded Controls 
Siebel ActiveX controls are available in Downloaded folder

Siebel ActiveX control test automation is running in process

Siebel controls in Assembly folder

Siebel addons are enabled in IE11

Siebel URL is added in Trusted sites
 [Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRQo2.png)

[Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIeRP.png)

Configured Siebel settings & downloaded Controls 
Siebel ActiveX controls are available in Downloaded folder

Siebel ActiveX control test automation is running in process

Siebel controls in Assembly folder

Siebel addons are enabled in IE11

Siebel URL is added in Trusted sites

Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy

Elements which are present in the highlighted control are not able to spy

Configured Siebel settings & downloaded Controls 
Siebel ActiveX controls are available in Downloaded folder

Siebel ActiveX control test automation is running in process

Siebel controls in Assembly folder

Siebel addons are enabled in IE11

Siebel URL is added in Trusted sites

Comment: I don't know anything about IBM RFT nor testing automation, but I know that IE 11 is NOT supported by Siebel 7.8. The latest supported version is IE8, according to Oracle: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1627168.1 . So  that might be your issue.

Comment: Thank you  AJPerez